# Removing some tabs on account page not working

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend

I have created this file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="downloadable_customer_products_list" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

in the following folder : `app/design/frontend/Magento/MyTheme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml`.

But this doesn't work. any idea what's am I missing ? 
I have tried to :

- `magento cache:clear` & `magento cache:flush`
- `magento setup:upgrader` & `magento setup:di:compile`.

None above solutions are working and the tabs like newsletter,product-list,prodcuts-reviews is still appear.

Here is my code structure look like :

```
 ▾ [✗]app/ 
  ▾ [✗]design/
    ▾ adminhtml/
    ▾ [✗]frontend/Magento/Aura/
      ▸ etc/
      ▸ i18n/
      ▸ layout/
      ▸ Magento_Catalog/
      ▾ [✗]Magento_Customer/layout/
          [✹]customer_account.xml
      ▸ Magento_Newsletter/email/
      ▸ Magento_Theme/
      ▸ media/
      ▸ web/
        composer.json
        registration.php
        requirejs-config.js
        theme.xml
```

As you can seeon the `Magento_Customer/layout` there is some xml file where I put the code above.

Comment: Which theme are used?

Comment: @SHPatel I'm using Aura

Comment: Give me your theme path.

Comment: @SHPatel this is my theme path : `app/design/frontend/Magento/Aura/` and I added the `Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml` for the xml file to remove the some tabs

Comment: Your xml must be in `app/design` folder not in `app/code/design`.

Comment: @PrincePatel yes sorry for typo, I have keep in in my `app/design/frontend/Magento/Aura`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep this code in your xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

You have giving reference for downloadable product is wrong.

Remove var and clear cache.

Comment: I have tried delete the `var/` and clear the cache and also your suggestion on xml file. But still not working

Comment: You can keep above code in xml file and check.

Comment: I'm noob in magento , keep in xml file ? where is the exact location ?

Comment: You can keep it in app/design/frontend/Magento/MyTheme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml file

Comment: the menus tabs on account setting still appear. :'(

Comment: please show your full code which you have tried in your module or theme

Comment: Updated with my folder structrue.